# Constructor DI in Navigation Using Caliburn.Micro Possible?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Is there a better way of doing it than this?:

```
ActivateItem(Ioc.Get<PageOneViewModel>());
```

I'm not a big fan of the Service Locator pattern. Is there any other DI hook available for such navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `PageOneViewModel` a dependency of your conductor (assuming your conductor is being resolved through a container).

In your app bootstrapper, register `PageOneViewModel`:

```
container = new SimpleContainer();
//...
container
    .PerRequest<MyViewModel>()
    .PerRequest<PageOneViewModel()>;
```

And in your conductor:

```
public MyViewModel : Conductor
{
    // require PageOneViewModel as a dependency
    public MyViewModel(PageOneViewModel pageOne)
    {
        PageOne = pageOne;
    }

    PageOneViewModel PageOne { get; set; }

    public override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        ActivateItem(PageOne);
    }
}
```

Note that I am using `SimpleContainer` (the one that comes with Caliburn Micro) here. It should work with other DI containers.

Comment: Thanks Doom5. That looks like a good solution. It might get a bit heavy if my Conductor is conducting a massive number of views. Loading them all up front. But I guess that is the trade-off. In any case, even if Caliburn.Micro did have a DI hook which worked to inject into ActivateItem, it would most like be doing a Service Location in the background. I'm sure Mark Seemann probably has a strong view on the matter :)